# A word for a special type of school examinations

Tags: single-word-requests

The ministry of education in our country has invented a new type of examination for slow students, who have  educational problems. Those students have failed many times. My question is: is there a special word for this exam? By the way, we use " make-up exam" for the students who failed one time only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An adjective used for such situations in general (not specific to examinations) is ***remedial***.

ODO:

> **[remedial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remedial)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Provided or intended for children with learning difficulties:
>    ‘remedial education’

Answer (score 0):

A term that is used by some school districts or departments of education is **modified assessment**.

Here is the first paragraph of the *California Department Of Education*'s webpage entitled *California Modified Assessment (CMA) Pilot Test*:

> In April 2007, the United States Department of Education enacted
>   regulations for an alternate assessment based on modified achievement
>   standards. The California Department of Education, in response to the
>   federal regulations, developed and implemented the California Modified
>   Assessment (CMA) as an alternate assessment of the California content
>   standards based on modified achievement standards for children with
>   disabilities who have an individualized education program (IEP).

http://www.cde.ca.gov/ta/tg/sr/cmastar.asp

The term **alternate assessment** is used by the *Ohio Department Of Education*. Here is part of its webpage *Ohio’s Alternate Assessment for Students with Significant Cognitive Disabilities (AASCD)*:

> Ohio’s Alternate Assessment for Students with Significant Cognitive
>   Disabilities (AASCD) is aligned to Ohio’s Learning Standards–Extended
>   (OLS-E) and designed to allow students with significant cognitive
>   disabilities to demonstrate their knowledge and skills in an
>   appropriately rigorous assessment.

http://education.ohio.gov/Topics/Testing/Ohio-English-Language-Proficiency-Assessment-OELPA/Ohios-Alternate-Assessment-for-Students-with-Sign